# Change Vim's icon

Tags: vim, icons

I'm on a Linux Machine ( Ubuntu ) and I use (g)Vim which is my favorite, I love everything but the icon, I like MacVim's icon but gVim's icon has a lot to be desired, is there a way to useea custom icon ( Looking into the runtime or something like that ). By the Way the icon I want to replace is http://drbl.in/SSQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool icon. Try this:

1. Right click on **Applications** button (typically top left of your screen, for English installation) - select ***Edit Menus***.
2. Select the menu category under which gVim resides - for me this is ***Accessories***.
3. Right click on the gVim item and select ***Properties*** (or click the same button on the right).
4. Click the icon button on the popup and pick whatever you'd like.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a similar way to do this which will change the icon in the Window List on gnome-panel?

gvim and firefox are the two I use which do not adhere to the icon theme.

thanks